# How do i solve android.view.InflateException when running an app

Tags: android

My app crashes every time I run it on the emulator. I get a message saying Myapp stopped working .I am new to android and I am using android studio . I looked at the Logcat output and this is what I get

```
06-12 14:41:21.160  27245-27245/? I/art? Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
06-12 14:41:21.310  27245-27245/? D/AndroidRuntime? Shutting down VM
06-12 14:41:21.320  27245-27245/? E/AndroidRuntime? FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.machimanapc.btdt, PID: 27245
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.machimanapc.btdt/com.example.machimanapc.btdt.QuizSplashActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class leanerLayout
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class leanerLayout
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:757)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
            at com.example.machimanapc.btdt.QuizActivity.onCreate(QuizActivity.java:17)
            at com.example.machimanapc.btdt.QuizSplashActivity.onCreate(QuizSplashActivity.java:20)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.leanerLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.machimanapc.btdt-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:571)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:665)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:65)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
            at com.example.machimanapc.btdt.QuizActivity.onCreate(QuizActivity.java:17)
            at com.example.machimanapc.btdt.QuizSplashActivity.onCreate(QuizSplashActivity.java:20)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.leanerLayout
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 26 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
​
```

Comment: I think you probably just misspelled `LinearLayout` as `leanerLayout` in your xml. If `leanerLayout` is a custom view of yours then you need to use the fully qualified class name, as in `com.example.leanerLayout`.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have a `<leanerLayout>` tag in your layout XML file. There is nothing named that in the Android SDK. If you have created your own custom `leanerLayout` subclass of `View` or `ViewGroup`, you will need to fully-qualify the class name (e.g., `<com.tlhani.leanerLayout>` instead of `<leanerLayout>`).

Answer (score 1):

In your `QuizSplashActivity` contentView xml file has syntax error, you  have `leanerLayout` and you probably meant `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a Syntex error. Thanks for your help.